# how to join tables to show related results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two tables `CHART` and `COMMENTS`.

When someone post a message first I would like to display only the comment field if there are no comments or both comments and comment field if there are some comments and so on. How can I join the two tables to output every each message with its comments? The following is the structure of my two tables rows.

table CHART: `id`, `msg`, `msg_id`

table COMMENTS: `id`, `comment`, `comment_id`

CREATE TABLE `chart` (
`msg` TEXT NOT NULL ,
`date` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`time` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`msg_id` VARCHAR( 255) NOT NULL ,
) ENGINE = InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `comments` (
`comment` TEXT NOT NULL ,
`date` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`time` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`comment_id` VARCHAR( 255) NOT NULL ,
) ENGINE = InnoDB

Comment: SELECT * FROM CHART as ch  LEFT JOIN COMMENTS as cm ON ch.id=cm.id has worked but every time new user comment the message it is creating the old message with the new comment instead of adding the comment bellow the message

Answer (score 0):

To SELECT all Comments WHICH have messages try

```
  SELECT * FROM CHART as ch INNER JOIN COMMENTS as cm ON ch.id=cm.id
```

To SELECT all Comments WHICH have messages  or not

```
   SELECT * FROM CHART as ch  LEFT JOIN COMMENTS as cm ON ch.id=cm.id
```

Note `*` Will SELECT all Columns From BOTH TABLEs You can define `Field Names to Select Desired columns

Comment: thanks for the reply allow me to take sometime to try this and come back to you later seems it will work

Comment: SELECT * FROM CHART as ch LEFT JOIN COMMENTS as cm ON ch.id=cm.id has worked but every time new user comment the message it is creating the old message with the new comment instead of adding the comment bellow the message

Comment: you Might have some other problem. Can you share the sample data of Both tables on `sqlfiddle` so i can better understand your problem

Comment: There might be a problem with your `INSERTS`

Comment: sorry but i don't know what is sqlfiddle? or do you mean i have to post my code i used to create the tables?

Comment: Yes you need to `POST`  Your code and http://sqlfiddle.com/ is a service where you create table and test data

Answer (score 0):

This is a way of doing it

```
SELECT ch.id , ch.msg , ch.msg_id , co.id , co.comment , co.comment_id FROM chart AS ch, comments AS co WHERE ch.id=co.id
```

Comment: karina its not working and i think you have forgotten WHERE ch.id=c.id to be WHERE ch.id=co.id